# White screen appearing when trigger a button

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-alertdialog, android-button

why does every time that I trigger the button it makes my screen white. But the values are getting remove.
Here is my code for it where it throws error.

```
final String uniqueKey = requestFormArrayList.get(position).getRequestid();
        final DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("ResearchRequest").child(uniqueKey);
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    String termsAgreement = snapshot.child("requestStatus").getValue(String.class);
                            if(termsAgreement.equals("accepted")){
                                holder.acceptresearch_request.setText("accepted");
                                holder.acceptresearch_request.setEnabled(false);
                                holder.deleteresearch_request.setEnabled(false);
                                holder.publishresearch_request.setEnabled(true);
                            }
                            else if (termsAgreement.equals("published")){
                                holder.acceptresearch_request.setEnabled(false);
                                holder.deleteresearch_request.setEnabled(false);
                                holder.publishresearch_request.setText("published");
                                holder.publishresearch_request.setEnabled(false);
                            }
                            else{
                                holder.acceptresearch_request.setEnabled(true);
                                holder.deleteresearch_request.setEnabled(true);
                                holder.publishresearch_request.setEnabled(false);
                            }
            }
```

the code above makes the button enable/disable depends on the value on the condition. But every time I delete or trigger the delete button it turns the screen white and go back to the MainActivity but it deletes the data without issue, it's just that it turns white instead of toasting and here's my code for it.

```
holder.deleteresearch_request.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                alert.setTitle("Delete Research Record");
                alert.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete");

                alert.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        final String uniqueKey = requestFormArrayList.get(position).getRequestid();
                        final DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("ResearchRequest").child(uniqueKey);
                        databaseReference.removeValue().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    Log.i("firebase", "Throwing exception");
                                    throw new RuntimeException(task.getException());
                                }
                                else {
                                    Toast.makeText(context, "Research has been deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                        });

                    }
                });
                alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                alert.show();
            }
        });
```

EDIT: This is the error that throws at me, I've searched about the NullPointerException here. But I don't quite follow

```
2021-01-07 16:37:28.706 25163-25163/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.citeresearchrepository, PID: 25163
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.citeresearchrepository.AdminAdapter.AdminRequestFormAdapter$1.onDataChange(AdminRequestFormAdapter.java:60)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:75)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:63)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:55)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:900)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:219)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8347)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1055)
```

Should I add another condition where termsAgreement.isEmpty() ? I think it's on the condition above since when you deleted it, there's no termsAgreement.equals("deleted"); in the database, any idea on for solution with this one?

Comment: if your task isn't successful, you're throwing a runtime exception, are you sure that isn't causing your problem ?

Comment: Null object reference click on it(`AdminRequestFormAdapter.java:60`). In which line it is sending you to? If you say, than I can understand what's wrong happening right here...

Comment: @Istiak `String termsAgreement = snapshot.child("requestStatus").getValue(String.class);` this one, I think when deleted there's no termsAgreement.equals("delete"); on the database so that's why. I guess.

Comment: @a_local_nobody hello, I have commented it, sorry for the late reply.

Comment: I have edited my post, thank you.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

```
String termsAgreement = snapshot.child("requestStatus").getValue(String.class);
                        if(termsAgreement.equals("accepted")){
                            holder.acceptresearch_request.setText("accepted");
                            holder.acceptresearch_request.setEnabled(false);
                            holder.deleteresearch_request.setEnabled(false);
                            holder.publishresearch_request.setEnabled(true);
                        }
                        else if (termsAgreement.equals("published")){
                            holder.acceptresearch_request.setEnabled(false);
                            holder.deleteresearch_request.setEnabled(false);
                            holder.publishresearch_request.setText("published");
                            holder.publishresearch_request.setEnabled(false);
                        }
                        else{
                            holder.acceptresearch_request.setEnabled(true);
                            holder.deleteresearch_request.setEnabled(true);
                            holder.publishresearch_request.setEnabled(false);
                        }
```

Here, your `termsAgreement` is null. Look at top line you wrote that `String.class`. String is data type. So, how you are calling it? I think that's why you are getting error. Maybe, you actually wanted to write `string.class`. On `.getValue(String.class)` you are unable to call value. That's why you are getting error.

Comment: I think the error is that, when deleted, the ID is already gone that's why it lets me out of the current activity instead of toasting it. Uhm, I already put String.class on the .getValue() tho. With the code you posted above, did u changed something since it's the same as what I currently have mine which has problem.

Comment: `termsAgreement` value is null. It has nothing. That's why you are getting the error.